# Is there any ways to print 2D Array much faster?

Tags: c++

I need to increase speed in printing 2D Array. 
Is there any ways to do that?

```
char arr[50][50] = {'#' ....};
while (true) {
  for (auto i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
      cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Replacing the `endl` with a `'\n'` might help a little. No need to flush every line.

Comment: Well as you have it you're printing the array an infinite amount of times. If you take away the outer while loop you will only print it once.

Comment: I guess I just have not studied the output stream enough.  You are making 2500 calls to std::cout <<.  As an old c programmer, I always wonder if a sprintf followed by a singled printf wouldn't be faster.

Comment: You'll want to remove "magic numbers" like `50` from your code and replace that with something like `const size_t size = 50` where you can change one variable and have everything flow through properly.

Comment: What sort of "speed" do you need? Normally C++ barfs out stuff faster than the terminal can keep up.

Comment: @Gardener: If `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` is used, I suspect not. And using that line in this code might yield some improvement.

Comment: I have a Function that changing this Array and I need to print that Array out multiple times to see the result.

Number 50 set for just an example. I have a #define SIZE 50.

Comment: @FredLarson is there ever a reason to not do that? Assuming you don't use stdio of course

Comment: @Ayxan: I don't generally bother, since I'm not usually that concerned about I/O performance. But indeed, probably the only reason not to use it is if you actually need stdio syncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but if (after profiling) it is the multiple calls to `cout` that are causing performance issues, consider using a type that can be passed to `cout` all at once.

Here is a silly example using `string` but there's nothing stopping you defining your own type with stream operators.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Coord_2D
{
    size_t x = 0;
    size_t y = 0;
};

Coord_2D index_to_coords(size_t index, const Coord_2D& dimensions)
{
    return {index % dimensions.x, index / dimensions.x};
}

size_t coords_to_index(const Coord_2D& coords, const Coord_2D& dimensions)
{
    return coords.y * dimensions.x + coords.x;
}

int main()
{
    Coord_2D dimensions = {50, 50};

    std::string arr(dimensions.x * dimensions.y, '0'); // "zero" the array;

    // alter the element at (23, 31) for the sake of example
    arr[coords_to_index({23, 31}, dimensions)] = 'F';

    std::cout << arr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ty so much. You helped me a lot!

Comment: If you wanna to know what I did, check my GitHub: https://github.com/Demosword/PerfectMazeGenerator. Maze_with_visual.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using sprintf with printf**

By using sprintf() for each row, you effectively do 50 memcpy() of length 50 calls rather than 2500 character copy calls.  Unless the compiler can optimize the copies to the output stream the memcpy()'s seem likely to be a little faster

Well, I am sure there are some buffering problems with my terminal, but the OP has the duty to do the real measurements.  On my terminal using the following code, I got the following for the two loops:

```
Duration1: 39459

Duration2: 171
```

I have never used `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio` before, so if I should call that differently, I am open to suggestions.  It did not make any difference in my numbers.

So, the question was to provide an alternative method to print this out fast. Sprintf seems to be a viable option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
  char arr[50][50];

  // load the array
  for (auto i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = '#';
    }
  }

  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

  // print using cout
  for (auto i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
      std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
  std::cout << "Duration1: " << duration.count() << std::endl;

  auto start2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  char printbuffer[2550];
  // print using sprintf
  for (auto i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    sprintf(&printbuffer[i*50], "%s.50\n", &arr[i][0]);
  }
  printf("%.2550s", printbuffer);
  auto stop2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop2 - start2);
  std::cout << "Duration2: " << duration2.count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```